# Why am I getting white spaces before and after every single character when using regexp_replace?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to replace all special symbols with a space (' ').

What I have thus far is:

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '-|"|~|!|(|)|-', ' ') from tablename;
```

Starting COLUMN_NAME : `He!lo`
What I end up with :  `H e   l o`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats your expected result? maybe instead of ' ' use ''

Comment: Try as follow: ["|~|!|(|)|-]

Comment: You don't need to use so many `|`, just make it a set `[-"~!()]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is the `|(|)|` parentheses test. Parentheses are a special character in regex so you are actually testing `(|)` which is just capturing every character (the pipe does nothing here).

For example, you are capturing the character 'H' and then replacing that capture with the capture `H` and a space `' '`. It also means that any character appearing after this test (your hyphen) isn't going to get replaced since it was already caught in the capture.

That being said a better way to do this would be:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]', ' ')
```

The caret in the bracket says "If a character is found that isn't in these ranges"

Or, of your list of characters to test for is limited, then:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '["~!\(\)]', ' ')
```

Taking special care to escape regex special characters in the list with a backslash. [Here's a good resource for identifying special characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

> there are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the
>   caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or
>   pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus
>   sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), the
>   opening square bracket [, and the opening curly brace {,

Comment: `!-\(` creates a range in your regex.

Comment: @ctwheels Darn it all! I will fix. List of non-ALNUM characters in a regex has got to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: You can also use `[\W_]` for non-alphanumeric characters

Comment: There are only three characters with special meaning in a character class (bracket expression): the caret (not “carat”!), the dash and the closing square bracket. Moreover, they can’t be escaped - they must be placed where they can’t have their special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you may use this :

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '[^[:alpha:][:digit:]]+', '')  from tablename;
```

or 
more abbreviately

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '[^[:alnum:]]', '')  from tablename;
```

as @ctwheels suggested.

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdfd27/2)

Comment: You can simplify `[^[:alpha:][:digit:]]+` to `[^[:alnum:]]`

Answer (score 0):

Escape metacharacters `(` and `)`.

```
regexp_replace(column_name, '-|"|~|!|\(|\)|-', ' ')
```